# Are there any metrics for both performance and energy efficiency?

Tags: parallel-processing, metrics, hpc, energy

For many parallel programs, the parallelization brings substantial cost, making the speedup sublinear. In this case, the parallel versions are less energy efficient than sequential one.
However, people may care both the time performance and energy efficiency, are there any specific metrics commonly used for this purpose?

More specifically, a metric that can determine the number of threads for best energy and performance goal.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_per_watt ?

Comment: @nos Thanks! That one is more suitable to evaluate architecture design. But in my case, the hardware is fixed. The tunable parameter is the number of threads to use.

Answer (score 3):

The most common metric is performance per watt. Take a look at the "Green500 List". Wikipedia also has an article on performance per watt. The metric is not as clear cut as it first appears because "performance" is not clear cut. FLOPS is very popular at the moment but it has a lot of deficiencies. I disagree that performance/watt can't be used to evaluate the performance of software. Depending upon your application, you may want to use performance/watt/sec.

I don’t know why you want to determine energy efficiency if parallelism is costing you. In fact, I don’t really understand how parallelism can be decreasing energy efficiency unless you are using a single core machine, doing pure computation, and are doing a lot of thrashing between threads. I’m guessing that this is not your own code.

Software power efficiency: The most important two factors are:

- getting your computation done faster
- making sure that periods between computation are truly idle

These factors break down into a whole host of other more concrete guidelines:

- avoid timing interrupts and (shutter) polling
- minimize synchronization constructs
- exploit parallelism (thread and vectorization)
- use a good optimizing compiler
- use a thread pool if you are continuously creating and terminating a lot of threads
- use efficient high performance libraries
- avoid virtual machines (e.g. java and flash)
- use a modern (tickless) OS
- etc. etc. etc

Dividing your computation between parallel threads should decrease computation times, or else why add its complications? (Yes, I understand that some programming constructs, such as recursion, can result in simpler and cleaner code but worse performance, but these are exceptions.) Decreasing computation should increase energy efficiency. If it doesn't, look at the algorithm and code practice.

If you can give me more detail about your app, I may be able to make more concrete suggestions.